# How to yield an Exception in a stream so that it can be caught in widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't seem to find a way to intentionally yield or throw an error in a stream in such a way that can be used by an AsyncValue widget in the tree (using Riverpod for State Management).

```
class AsyncValueWidget<T> extends StatelessWidget {
   AsyncValueWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.value,
      required this.data
      : super(key: key);
  final AsyncValue<T> value;
  final Widget Function(T) data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return value.when(
      data: data
      error: (e, st) => Center(child: ErrorMessageWidget(e.toString())),
      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the stream in my fake repo to return a value in certain cases and Exception in other cases:
`

```
  Stream<T> function() async* {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    switch (condition) {
      case condition 1:
        yield value1;
        break;
      case condition 2:
        yield value2;
        break;
      case condition 3:
        // neither these work
        throw Exception('You should not be able to call this function under this condition');
        yield* Stream.error()...
      case condition 4:
        yield null;
        break;
    }
  }
```

`

Unfortunately, the Exception/Error does not seem to make it to the widget and I get a nasty red screen. I've also tried try/catch to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with a service, I recommend FutureBuilder. for more info you can check here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> ```
> FutureBuilder(
>               future: controller.mainFuture.value,
>               builder: (context, snapshot) {
>                 switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
>                   case ConnectionState.active:
>                   case ConnectionState.waiting:
>                     return Container(
>                       color: Colors.white,
>                       width: context.width,
>                       height: context.height,
>                       child: globalShimmer(height: 50, itemCount: 10),
>                     );
>                   case ConnectionState.done:
>                     if (snapshot.hasError) {
>                       return Container();
>                     }
>                     return Container();
>                   default:
>                     return Container();
>                 }
>               });
> ```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not really looking to change up my state management approach. I just wanted to know why I am unable to catch the error emitted from the stream I made

Comment: Which state management method are you using?

Comment: i using getX - state management

Answer (score 0):

To return a fake error to a stream using riverpod, just simply return `Stream.error('Something went wrong')`:

```html
final fakeErrorStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<T>>(
  (ref) {
    return Stream.error('something went wrong');
  },
);
```

or

```html
  Stream<List<T>> watchWhatever() => Stream.error('Something went wrong.');
```

Your `AsyncValueWidget` will catch this error from the UI.